# How do I run chkdsk to repair my laptop's hard drive?

Tags: chkdsk

My laptop's hard drive is failing, so I deleted the hard drive and tried to re-install Windows 8.1. It gave me the error code 0x8007045D, so I asked a question and got help to try and fix it with the command prompt. I want to do a `chkdsk` to see if I can repair the hard drive. How do I do this?

Comment: chkdsk isn't going to repair anything.  Its going to find any corrupt file caused by a corrupt file system and delete them.  If your drive is failing before a scan it will still be failing after a scan and you will likely end up with data loss.

Comment: Try @TD.512 answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it from the installation media:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> at the Install Windows prompt
2. Run `DISKPART`
3. Run `LIST VOL` to list volumes available to check.
4. If the letter of the drive you want to check isn't there, go to B
5. Run `EXIT` once to exit diskpart.
6. Run `CHKDSK D: /X` substituting `D` with your drive letter.

---

### B

1. While in Diskpart, run `LIST DISK` to find your disk number
2. Run `SEL DISK 0` to select disk `0`. Replace `0` with the number of your disk.
3. Run `CRE PAR PRI` to create a primary partition
4. Run `FOR FS=NTFS LABEL="Local Disk" QUICK` to format the partition quickly as NTFS.
5. Run `ASSIGN` to assign the partition a volume mount point, or drive letter.
6. Run `LIST VOL` to list volumes available to check.
7. Run `EXIT` once to exit diskpart.
8. Run `CHKDSK D: /X` substituting `D` with your drive letter.

**BEWARE that CHKDSK will attempt repairs by writing over the damaged block, and mark it as useless.**

Answer (score 0):

`CHKDSK` is intended to detect and fix errors on a disk / partition. You can open a command prompt and type `CHKDSK /?` to get a description of the syntax. The re-install of Windows would have done the same thing as a `CHKDSK` i.e. cleaned up unreadable sectors of the disk. In your case, I am guessing you only have one partition - i.e. the system partition `C` that you just re-installed Windows 8.1 on. If this is correct,  you may be able to run   `CHKDSK C: /F`   - there is no need to run diskpart.

**HOWEVER**:
If your drive is failing, `CHKDSK` will NOT be able to help you: it MIGHT postpone the inevitable demise of your drive. Since you have just re-installed Windows, I am guessing there are few if any user files on your system which makes this the ideal time to purchase a new drive and re-install Windows on that new, clean drive. If you continue with the current, faulty drive, it is only a matter of time until it fails completely and takes any and all user data files with it.

Comment: "It gave me the error code 0x8007045D" This I addressed in a previous question, stating the HDD was already failing, and Windows 8.1 would refuse to install, due to that error. This means that the OP would not be able to boot into windows, and drive `C:` would have been assigned to the installation medium, which leaves the internal HDDs volume as some other letter, which is why `DISKPART` is needed, to find, or create, assign and find the correct drive letter. As a side note, you need `/X` to force unmount the drive so `CHKDSK` can go through and modify the partition as needed.

Comment: Just to finish, If you'd actually read the question, you'd see that the install exited with an error, rendering these comments: "The re-install of Windows..." "...just re-installed Windows 8.1 on..." null, as you haven't read the question, rather, only skimmed it for the basis

Answer (score 0):

Chkdsk can not solve your falling hard drive. I suggest that you back up all your files while you can then, look for a replacement.